# Mongoose JS, my scoreboard implementation performance

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm developing score board (top 10 scores) and I am thinking if I could write thie code better way?

The code looks like:

```
const ScoreBoard = mongoose.model("ScoreBoard",
new mongoose.Schema({
nickname:String,
score:{type:Number,index:true}
})


    getTopTenScores(req,res){
    ScoreBoard.find()
.sort({score:-1})
.limit(10)
.then(r=>res.json(r))
      }
```

I think this code may fail on larger databases. I plan to use redis in the future, but for now I would like to stick to mongodb with mongoose.

So the question is - Can i make the code more efficent?

Comment: What makes you assume that this would fail on larger databases?

Comment: I have a feeling that with larger amounts of data, e.g. 1 million, it will take too long to sort by score. Or will this code can handle even with more data?

Comment: That's what you defined the index for, isn't it?

Comment: I know that index speeds up sorting, but with a large amount of data, won't it be even with index too slow? Or however, do I not fully understand how the index works?

Comment: It doesn't need to sort any data, the [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#index-use) is already sorted. All it needs to do is read the 10 topmost entries.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will indeed fail in larger databases. I suggest you use indexes in `find()`'s parameter, which will improve the speed.

Apart from that, you can use `lean()` after `find()` if you want to get a simple Javascript object, and not a Mongoose one.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the concept of sharding. I read a little about it. All in all, after adding the indexes and lean() method, will this code work fine? For example, with a one million documents, won't sorting even with an index be too demanding?

Comment: Frankly saying I do not remember all optimization methods  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/  here is useful link to read. With 1 million , it depends on hardware and you can use sharding to split 1 mil DB to 10 with 100k in each , for example names with A letter will be in first Db and so on and when you need something just query the right Db